# How to echo runnable app path, registered in Windows environment variable

Tags: java, windows, bash, command-line, command-prompt

Suppose I set the **Path** inside Windows System Variable the following :

c:\path\to\java\bin

and my app is **java.exe** under the above path.

I'm looking for a way to get the path "c:\path\to\java\bin" by using windows command prompt.

Comment: you are right but I need also to elimibate the last part "java.exe"

Comment: for %i in (java.exe) do @echo. %~$PATH:i:  -> how to remove the java.exe from last part of the echo path from the output of this ? please give me one line code

Comment: I also found the solution bur I can developed the above code and wrap into this :

SET _test=123456789abcdef0
SET _result=%_test:~0,-7%
ECHO %_result%          =123456789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Windows nor a powershell expert, but some googling gave me Linux functionality of `which` and `sed` in powershell ..

```
PS H:\> where.exe java
C:\JDK\1.6.0.31\bin\java.exe
C:\JDK64\1.8.0.45\bin\java.exe
C:\JDK64\1.6.0.31.1\bin\java.exe
C:\JDK64\1.7.0.79\bin\java.exe
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
PS H:\> where.exe java | %{$_ -replace "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.exe", ""}
C:\JDK\1.6.0.31\bin\
C:\JDK64\1.8.0.45\bin\
C:\JDK64\1.6.0.31.1\bin\
C:\JDK64\1.7.0.79\bin\
C:\Windows\System32\
PS H:\>
```

Comment: just remove java.exe from this command -> for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.%~$PATH:i